# Apex REST CORS request

Tags: rest, angular, cors

I'm getting an error upon calling my REST endpoint from a visualforce page with Angular.

My error is this:

> XMLHttpRequest cannot load https://... A wildcard '*' cannot be used
>   in the 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header when the credentials flag
>   is true. Origin https://... is thereforce not allowed access

Here's some similar code to setup my REST endpoint:

```
RestRequest foobar = RestContext.request;
RestContext.request.addHeader('Content-Type', 'application/json');
// I've tried to set this following line to a dynamic url like so
// RestContext.request.addHeader('Access-Control-Allow-Origin', '*');
RestContext.request.addHeader('Access-Control-Allow-Origin', 'https://...')
```

After doing so, i'm still unable to do so.

What does one have to do to properly setup a CORS REST Endpoint?

Comment: Did you ever find the solution to this? ( it won't let me comment, sorry )

Comment: No not at this moment.